# I can not deploy azure functions (v2) with visual studio (2019 and 2017)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I deploy an Azure Function with a service bus topic trigger from visual Studio. When I try to run the function I become an error.

> Service Unavailable -
> https://*.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/Function1  Session Id:
> 2f3a817b55eb4b188e2c3110d50169fd Timestamp: 2019-02-21T00:31:26.000Z

And when I click on the function host URL, I get this message:

> Function host is not running.

I do the same in browser (create the function with the same trigger) everything will run fine. Without any problems.

What can I do to use visual studio to deploy azure functions?

Reagards

Update:
I becone this error

> 2019-02-21T18:34:39
>
> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access
> the file 'D:\home\site\diagnostics\settings.json' because it is being
> used by another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
> errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
> System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
> access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
> bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
> msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
> access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
> msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding,
> Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean
> checkHost)    at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path,
> Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)    at
> System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)    at
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.BaseTraceListener.ReadConfigFile()

Comment: Have you added the service bus connection string in Application settings? With name identical to the value of `Connection` parameter in code.

Comment: The was a set from Visual Studio

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it clearly. Does it mean you have inserted the setting when publishing, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings)? Note that settings in `local.settings.json` are not published to Azure site.

Comment: I did the way from the link.

Comment: Have you checked the host logs? Go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host`.

Comment: I dont can access the site https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net becuase "Function host is not running" return

Comment: Hmm, tried restarting function app?

Comment: yes I try to restart the function

Comment: Now I find the error. I put it in an update inside the question. But i find no answer

Comment: The error you found seems not related to your problem, is it acceptable to create a new function app?

Comment: When I create a new Function app. There is the same problem. It comes the same error message. When I create the function app inside the browser and edit it inside the browser it works.

Comment: Sorry it's beyond my ability. I suggest you create a support request to get official help, see last `Help+Support` tab on left sidebar in Azure portal.